# Delete user from iTunesConnect

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

I have added my developer as iTunesConnect User for the development period. Now that the development is done, I want to remove him from the users but I get the option of only unticking him which only stops him from getting the emails for new builds but he can still login into my account and access my apps, users & roles and the previlidges assigned to him as technical guy. I want to remove him from the users list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I refer you to check this page https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/iTunesConnect_Recipes/Articles/ManageTeam.html

Comment: the link is down now